How nodejs can run on multiple OS
I am fresher on Nodejs, I understand nodeJS have V8 engine and LibUV. LivUV will process asynchronous processing and it write by C programing language.
How C work for across OS?
My reference documents:
https://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html
https://blog.libtorrent.org/2012/10/asynchronous-disk-io/

Because C can be translated into machine code for any machine or operating system ..... it still needs to be compiled for that machine.

write by C programing language -- Do not tag C++ if your question concerns C.

C is a system-level programming language that can directly interact with the operating system's APIs (like memory management, file I/O, network operations).
When we want to write cross-platform code in C (i.e., code that works on different operating systems like Linux, Windows, or macOS), they often use conditional compilation or abstraction layers that call different OS-specific APIs depending on which OS the code is being compiled for.

thanks Harsh Dasila. do you have any documentation mention about abstraction layers for OS specific APIs. The compile time and runtime will be difference between OS?
